# How to locate and click an ng-click button in a repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, repeater

I need to test an AngularJS web page using Selenium WebDriver and Protractor.

HTML snippet to be tested:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">
        Item1
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">
        description
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">
        1234
    </td>
    <td>
        <div ng-click="AddItem(item.id)" class="btn">Add Item</div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">
        Item2
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">
        description
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">
        1235
    </td>
    <td>
        <div ng-click="AddItem(item.id)" class="btn">Add Item</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

it looks like this:

[screenshot of the html angular page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8TIi.png)

I already went through the documentation, tutorials on youtube and googled it but I still don't understand how to locate and click "Add Item" for a specific item with a specific item id.

can you please explain to me how it's done?

Comment: I guess Selenium can access htmls elements with their IDs. If you provided unique IDs to your div those having ng-click then you can access those elements in Selenium. To provide unique IDs you can add id="ItemAdd{{$index}}" to your DIV tag

Comment: @user3249448 Do you mean the website developer needs to add IDs or should I do that somehow through my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific id you are looking for wont be in the DOM, which means you cannot locate an element using that approach.

The following is the code which i personally use:

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).filter(function(row){
 return row.all(by.tagName('td')).first().getText().then(function(val){
     return val === "Item1" //this can be your per your wish
  })
}).first().$('[ng-click="AddItem(item.id)"]').click();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Danny's answer,it is possible to find the item.id from the DOM using `evaluate()` method.Try the below code.

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).filter(function(row){
   return row.evaluate('item.id').then(function(id){
      return val === "1234";
    })
}).first().$('.btn').click();
```

Source: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate

Comment: Thank you. I went with Danny's answer because the first item field ("Item1", "item2", etc) is the only one that's not optional and is completely unique si I know for sure it will always be found and recognized as long as the record itself exists.